# Modify 120v lamp dimmer for LED bulb

Tags: led, dimmer, lamp

I have a "stick lamp" that has a pot/twistable dimmer with photocell. It works fine with a 24w Sylvania CFL bulb but won't light this 22w dimmable LED bulb (http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/80306780/). The LED bulb lights fine in a regular lamp. I read that maybe the lower wattage of the bulb or way the dimmer circuit works is causing issues.

Here's the dimmer:
http://www.ceilingfanswitch.com/product/lamp-dimmer-zing-ear-ze-02se/
[image]
[image]

I don't really care if the photocell works and I'm open to the idea of replacing the whole dimmer piece but not sure what to look for.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not something that can be easily diagnosed over the Internet. I see your LED bulb is dimmable and the dimmer specifically supports LED bulbs, so it should work. Try wiring your LED bulb in parallel to the CFL one and see if that works.

Comment: http://www.edn.com/design/power-management/4430321/How-to-make-LED-bulbs-dimmable

Comment: Can you add a small incandescent bulb in paralell?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the socket for the lamp is fairly deep and the bulb has a wider base than the CFL above the threads. Bending the center conductor up fixed the issue.

Comment: That's a non-compliant socket then.